# Convert hex code from TIFF to readable format

Tags: jupyter-notebook, hex, ascii, jpeg, decode

I am trying to read in the JPEG table from a TIFF file to locate sub-images in the TIFF file. (This is coming from a whole slide image svs file and I am trying to delete the label and macro image.) The JPEG table is hex encoded and I can't figure out to turn it to readable information to locate the sub-images.

I have tried unpacking the values. I don't want to save the file and open in Linux. I want to do this from within a jupyter notebook. I've tried for a while using "unpack" from IO core tools which didn't work. I also briefly tried BeautifulSoup, but it tells me that there is an invalid start byte. Here's the first line I am trying to decode:

```
b'\xff\xd8\xff\xdb\x00C\x00'
```

This line should return something like "JPEG image file..." I think  if I can translate this line I can do the rest of this JPEG table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used a python TIFF package to help find the pages of the TIFF file I was looking for.